# plotting dataframe values in loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a `csv` file named as `data.csv` and it contain [10000 rows x 1 columns] and i read the data as

```
a=read_csv("data.csv")

print(a)

                                                  dt
0     3.5257,3.5257,3.5257,3.5257,3.5257,3.5257,3.52...
1     3.3414,3.3414,3.3414,3.3414,3.3414,3.3414,3.34...
2     3.5722,3.5722,3.5722,3.5722,3.5722,3.5722,3.57...
.....
```

Now I want to plot each indexed rows in loop and want to save each plot in the name of index values . For example

```
i need to produce 0.jpg by using o indexed values ---->  3.5257,3.5257,3.5257,3.5257,3.5257,3.5257,3.52...
similarly 1.jpg by using 1 index values---->  3.3414,3.3414,3.3414,3.3414,3.3414,3.3414,3.34...
```

My code

```
a=read_csv("data.csv")
print(a)
for data in a:
    plt.plot(data)
```

Hope experts will help me providing the answer.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `savefig` to create image file:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for name, data in a['dt'].str.split(',').items():
    plt.plot(data)
    plt.savefig(f'{name}.jpg')
    plt.close()
```

`0.jpg`
[image]

`1.jpg`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the following `file.csv` example:

```
3.5257,3.5257,3.5257,3.5257,3.5257,3.5257,3.52
3.3414,3.3414,3.3414,3.3414,3.3414,3.3414,3.34
3.5722,3.5722,3.5722,3.5722,3.5722,3.5722,3.57
```

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) and Python [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("../file.csv", header=None)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(8, 4))
    ax.plot(row)
    fig.savefig(f"./{i}.png")
```